# How to get "Location" variable of a device manager item in command prompt

Tags: windows-10, device-manager

I have two devices connected to my computer, showing up as:

```
MOXA USB Serial Port (COM10)
MOXA USB Serial Port (COM2)
```

In Device manager, under ports, when I click the first, the Properties windows says "Location: on UPort 1130"
The second says "Location: on UPort 1110"

I need to be able to use command prompt to differentiate which is which (1110 vs 1130).

I tried this, but it doesn't give me the information I need.

```
C:\Users\myuser>wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'MOXA%'" get /value


Availability=
Caption=MOXA USB Serial Port (COM2)
ClassGuid={4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
CompatibleID=
ConfigManagerErrorCode=0
ConfigManagerUserConfig=FALSE
CreationClassName=Win32_PnPEntity
Description=MOXA USB Serial Port
DeviceID=MXUPORT\COM\6&amp;19BDFBDE&amp;4&amp;0000
ErrorCleared=
ErrorDescription=
HardwareID={"mxuport\com"}
InstallDate=
LastErrorCode=
Manufacturer=Moxa Inc.
Name=MOXA USB Serial Port (COM2)
PNPClass=Ports
PNPDeviceID=MXUPORT\COM\6&amp;19BDFBDE&amp;4&amp;0000
PowerManagementCapabilities=
PowerManagementSupported=
Present=TRUE
Service=mxuwdrv2
Status=OK
StatusInfo=
SystemCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName=INI-NO-PF0TMQDZ


Availability=
Caption=MOXA USB Serial Port (COM10)
ClassGuid={4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
CompatibleID=
ConfigManagerErrorCode=0
ConfigManagerUserConfig=FALSE
CreationClassName=Win32_PnPEntity
Description=MOXA USB Serial Port
DeviceID=MXUPORT\COM\6&amp;3F0A0B3&amp;0&amp;0000
ErrorCleared=
ErrorDescription=
HardwareID={"mxuport\com"}
InstallDate=
LastErrorCode=
Manufacturer=Moxa Inc.
Name=MOXA USB Serial Port (COM10)
PNPClass=Ports
PNPDeviceID=MXUPORT\COM\6&amp;3F0A0B3&amp;0&amp;0000
PowerManagementCapabilities=
PowerManagementSupported=
Present=TRUE
Service=mxuwdrv2
Status=OK
StatusInfo=
SystemCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName=INI-NO-PF0TMQDZ
```

I also tried this, but it also doesn't really give me what I need.

```
C:\Users\myuser>reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
    \Device\mxuport0    REG_SZ    COM2
    \Device\mxuport1    REG_SZ    COM10
```

Comment: How important is it if you get that location? I mean, the wmi query tells you the deviceID which is unique, so you do have a way to distinquish the device in cmd, all you need to do is get the devices in device manager linked by id and see what port it has so you know which is which.

Comment: I just connected two UPort 1130 devices and unfortunately that DeviceID is like you say, unique to each individual device, it's like a serial number. 3F0A0B3 vs 16AA5158 for these two. At my company we have a drawer full of these devices and staff pick ones at random to use, so unless I earmark two specific ones, I cannot use your solution. But I appreciate your answer.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. You see, I think this is an X-Y problem. You have a problem, came up with a solution and need help with that, but that solution may not be the best solution. Can you tell us why you need the location? What is ultimately the goal of being able to receive this info from cmd?

Comment: I am creating automated test equipment. I want any random test operator, with no requirements of computer knowledge, to be able to plug in one Moxa Uport-1110 RS232-USB adapter, and one Moxa Uport-1130 RS488-USB adapter, and the script should automatically be able to know which is which. The unit I am creating the test for has one connector for RS485 and one for RS233. I have landed on two workarounds, I either use some other type of adapter which identifies its COM-port differently, or I create an instruction system for the user to plug 1110, then press ok, then plug 1130. Not elegant but ok.

Comment: Given that you can iterate each device, can you perform an operation against both unit where one unit will always fail and the other unit always succeeds? As in, you then know which one is the 1110 and which one is the 1130 based on what unit fails?